# Pegar o texto do combobox e salvar no SqlServer - Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

Já pesquisei de diversas forma e tentei converter de todas as maneiras possíveis, porém sempre acabo no mesmo lugar.

Eu já consegui popular o ComboBox com às informações do SqlServer, e na hora de converter essa mesma informação e salvar no banco de dados só estou conseguindo salvar o ID da minha categoria escola e não o texto que está no ComboBox.

```
  public void ComboBox()
    { 
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=DESKTOP");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select* from Escolas", sqlConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ComboBoxEscola.DataSource = dt;
        ComboBoxEscola.ValueMember = "Id";
        ComboBoxEscola.DisplayMember = "Nome";

    }

    private void BtnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        aluno.EscolaId = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBoxEscola.SelectedValue.ToString()); 
        
        if (alunoManager.Add(aluno))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aluno salvo com sucesso.", "Informação!!!", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Limpar();
            TxtNome.Focus();
            ComboBoxEscola.Items.Clear();
            CarregarDadosluno();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao salvar aluno", "Atenção!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public class Escola
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar utilizar SelectedItem para esse caso, o SelectedValue é valor de ID, e o SelectedItem DESCRIÇÃO.

```
aluno.EscolaName = ComboBoxEscola.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado, já foi resolvido o problema.

Answer (score -1):

```
string texto = string.empty(); //declara uma variavel string 

texto = seucombobox.text;// pega o valor texto do combobox e joga na variavel string

//evento do botão gravar
 private void brnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
gravarNoBanco(id, texto);// chama a classe que vai gravar os dados no banco

}

// classe que vai gravar dados no banco
public void gravarNoBanco(int idCombobox, string valorCombobox)


{

// aqui informa as regras do insert no seu banco de dados

}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).